# Implementing a Windows form that changes during run-time based on a Listener class

Tags: c#, winforms, leap-motion

I am currently designing a GUI for a Leap Motion device (although my problem could arise with any type of listener device).

I am running my application in a Windows Form with the following code:

```
public partial class FormRecord : Form
{

    public FormRecord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateGUI(Frame frame)
    {
     //get information from captured frame 
     //update the GUI (specifically labels)
     customLabel0.Text = someValueFromFrame.ToString();
    }
```

//this method code was provided by Leap Motion on their website

```
    public static void RunMain() 
    {

        // Create a sample listener and controller
        SampleListener listener = new SampleListener();

        Controller controller = new Controller(); 
          //Controller is included in Leap.dll (from SDK) and is an instance of controller

        // Have the sample listener receive events from the controller
        controller.AddListener(listener);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit...");
        Console.ReadLine();



        // Remove the sample listener when done
        controller.RemoveListener(listener);
        controller.Dispose();
    }
```

//This class was also provided in the Leap Motion SDK

```
    class SampleListener : Listener
    {
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

        private void SafeWriteLine(String line)
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
        {

            SafeWriteLine("Initialized");
        }

        public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
        {

            SafeWriteLine("Connected");

        }

        public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
        {

            //Note: not dispatched when running in a debugger.
            SafeWriteLine("Disconnected");
        }

        public override void OnExit(Controller controller)
        {

            SafeWriteLine("Exited");
        }

        public override void OnFrame(Controller controller) //
        //public void OnFrame(Controller controller)
        {

            SafeWriteLine("Framed");
            //Do something useful with the captured frame

            // get the current frame
            Frame frame = controller.Frame();

            /* This is where my problem occurs */
           // attempt to use information from this form and call UpdateGUI(Frame frame)

        }
      }    
}
```

Basically, the problem is arising because of the difference in static vs. non-static nature of the two classes. For example, my application (Windows Form) is non-static because it is a form and you must be able to create several instances by nature. However, that is why I cannot simply call:

```
Form aForm = new Form();
aForm.UpdateGUI();
```

^^This creates a new form. I want to be able to fun the UpdateGUI() method on the original form.

I have also tried

```
  guiForm = ActiveForm;
```

and calling the label from there

```
 ActiveForm.customlbl0.Text = valueToDisplay;
```

More generally, I am trying to update a Windows Form based on data received from a Listener. This is causing me problems because I am having to struggle between static and non-static members. I would make it all one class, however I need to implement both form and Listener for the two components. How can I update a display with real-time data from a listener?

Edit: The listener is an implementation from the SDK file "LeapCSharp.Net4.0dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
public partial class FormRecord : Form
{
    Controller controller;

    public FormRecord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        controller = new Controller();
    }

    public void UpdateGUI()
    {
         Frame frame = controller.frame();

        //get information from captured frame 
        //update the GUI (specifically labels)
        customLabel0.Text = someValueFromFrame.ToString();
    }
```

If you use listeners be aware that each listener callback is called on its own thread. You usually cannot update objects accessed directly by a GUI framework (like Windows Forms, etc) from any thread other than the main thread. (I don't know the best way to do cross-thread communication in Windows forms, though.)

Comment: This did it! I was under the impression that it had to use a listener, but this was not the case. 

My only correction to this code would be technically, the way your solution is proposed, it would make more sense to have your second method as follows:
`public void UpdateGUI(Controller controller)`

because you are redefining the frame in the next line, overwriting what was brought in.

Comment: Listeners are only one way to get frames -- and often not the most straightforward because of threading issues. Also, I overlooked the Frame parameter in your existing code when I modified it (now edited). You wouldn't need to pass in the controller object either, since it is an instance property (unless whatever is invoking UpdateGUI() owned the controller instance rather than the FormRecord class)..

Answer (score 1):

I would make the constructor of SampleListener take an instance of your form class.  When you create the Listener pass in a reference to the form and store it in a private field.  That way you can call methods on it from inside the listener.

Another option would be to make your SampleListener class raise events for each event.  You can then hook the events from inside your form.

Comment: I'd go for the events, so `SampleListener` does not depend on the `Form` class.

Comment: Any chance you could throw together some code to help me out? I'm not quite sure how to implement those solutions.

Comment: The Listener can't update the form since it's callbacks are invoked on a non-GUI thread. You have to use events/delegates with this approach. I added an example that uses delegates to the Leap Motion docs: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/skeletal/csharp/devguide/Project_Setup_WinForms.html